# How to access a structure member without knowing the name?

Tags: c++, c, struct

How can we access a structure's member without knowing the name of it?

For example : This is my struct.

```
struct A
{
   int a;
   char b;  
   int c;
 }
```

Now I want to access char member of the struct A without using it's name.

I have only a pointer to that structure.

Example : struct A *temp;

Now I need to access with 'temp'.

I know the question is simillar to this [How would you access a C structure's members without knowing the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829966/how-would-you-access-a-c-structures-members-without-knowing-the-name),
but it doesn't clarified my doubt.

Comment: the question is a but odd because what exactly you want to excess if you don't know any of the inner members? lets say I have `Opaque opaqe` - what doyou want to excess exactly? give me an example.

Comment: What *do* you know about `struct A`? I assume you must know that it has exactly one `char` member (otherwise your question is ill-posed); do you also know what all of its other members are, and what order they're in, and so on?

Comment: @ruakh My struct memebers are in the same order which I have declared above and I want to access 'char b' from struct using 'temp' struct pointer

Comment: @Praveenupadrasta if you have a `struct A* temp`, you can just do `temp->b`. This should be covered in any basic book or tutorial on C.

Comment: @SigveKolbeinson HAHA :D No no,Not like that, consider I have just passed the struct pointer to a function and you don't know the name of the members present in the struct but you only know that the first member is of integer type, the second with char type and third with integer type. Now If I ask you to print the value in the second member of the struct, how would you do that? If you are still not clear with my question read the question provided in the link above.

Comment: Does the function take a pointer-to-struct-A (where `struct A` is forward declared) or pointer-to-void? Will it need to work for any arbitrary struct, or only `struct A`?

Comment: @SigveKolbeinson No just need to work only for struct A. Yes the function takes a parameter of pointer to struct A. Example: foo(struct A *temp){ }

Comment: @NiBZ, the function can take a pointer to a forward-declared struct A, and the function will not know its structure.

Comment: @SigveKolbeinson Err ... you're right, I did forgot about that. I removed my comment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should work

```
void *b=temp;
int *c = (int *) b;
cout<<"Value1: "<<*c <<endl;
char *cc =(char *) (b+4);
cout<<"Char1: "<<*cc<<endl;
c =(int *) (b+6);
cout<<"Value2: "<<*c<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, I understand you have the following function

```
struct A;
void foo( struct A * temp )
{
    // access temp->b here
}
```

If you can include the file that has struct A's definition, do so

```
#include "A.h"
void foo( struct A * temp )
{
    do_something_with_b(temp->b);
}
```

If you can't include the file, do what Luc Forget suggested in his answer:
Declare a `struct B` with identical structure, and cast `temp` to `struct B`. Because `struct B` have the same memory layout as `struct A`, accessing `((struct B*)temp)->e` is identical to accessing `A->b`.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question and for providing exact answer for it :)

Comment: Actually, if you don't have access to a header with the declaration of `struct A` just write the declaration yourself.  No need to call it `struct B` and do a cast.

Answer (score 1):

If you what are the structure fields, I think the simplest way of accessing the fields is to declare another structure Struct B with the same fields and casting your struct A* to struct B and then accessing the fields in a "traditional" way.
Here is a simple example of what I mean :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
    int a;
    char b;
    int c;
};

struct B {
    int d;
    char e;
    int f;
};

void printStruct(void* struct_ptr)
{
    struct B *tmp = struct_ptr; 
    fprintf(stdout, "a:%d b:%c c:%d\n", tmp->d, tmp->e, tmp->f);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct A test = { 42, 'A', 24 };
    printStruct(&test);
}
```

Here printStruct "doesn't know" the field names of Struct A but can access them

Comment: @MattMcNabb sorry I haven't noticed it.

Answer (score 1):

If You know the types and order of members **(as well as packing)** then You can create another struct and cast a pointer, like so:

```
struct AMirror {
  int a;
  char b;
  int c;
};
void function_to_use_struct(AMirror *ptr);
...
A *s;
...
function_to_use_struct((AMirror*)s);
```

Comment: adding to this: it works because structs with exactly the same members are guaranteed to have the same layout

Answer (score 0):

I guess one way is to cast and increment the `char*` , but in this case you must know the types and order of declarations of your members.

Comment: Can you clearly explain with me an example for the struct members listed above with the order I've declared.

Comment: Something like `char *tmp = (char *)temp; char b = tmp[sizeof(int)];` could work, if you have no definition of `struct A` in this code. But a more "clean" implementation would consist of a proper include and using `char b = temp->b`, as it would be safe to any reorder you could do in your struct.